# backspace doesn't work when running c++ program

Tags: bash

Whenever I use ./a.out to run a c/c++ program in bash, I cannot backspace when entering input. Instead I got a box with a question mark.

Comment: What is the output of `stty -a`? If you run `cat`, then press Ctrl+V Backspace Ctrl+C, what is printed on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

The *box with a question mark* sounds like the Unicode replacement character.  That could be displayed in this situation:

- the terminal uses UTF-8 encoding,
- someone has typed a multibyte character using the UTF-8 encoding,
- the backspace (or whatever one may term it) key is received, but
- only *part* of the character, i.e., the last *byte* is removed by the terminal driver, and
- the terminal, asked to (re)display has only an incomplete character, and
- shows the replacement character:

[image: Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFD)]

While Linux kernel has supported a `iutf8` flag for several years, this is not standardized, and generally not available on other systems ([OSX has it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stty.1.html), by the way).  Also (even if supported) there's the chance that it was turned off.

Further reading:

- [UTF-8 and Unicode FAQ for Unix/Linux](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html):

> The tty driver of any POSIX system supports a *“cooked”* mode, in which some primitive line editing functionality is available. In order to allow the character-erase function (which is activated when you press backspace) to work properly with UTF-8, someone needs to tell it not count continuation bytes in the range 0x80-0xBF as characters, but to delete them as part of a UTF-8 multi-byte sequence. Since the kernel is ignorant of the libc locale mechanics, another mechanism is needed to tell the tty driver about UTF-8 being used. Linux kernel versions 2.6 or newer support a bit IUTF8 in the `c_iflag` member variable of struct termios. If it is set, the “cooked” mode line editor will treat UTF-8 multi-byte sequences correctly. This mode can be set from the command shell with *“stty iutf8”*. Xterm and friends should set this bit automatically when called in a UTF-8 locale.

- [Backspace via SSH only deletes last byte of characters (no IUTF8 handling, requires standardisation work)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/394570)
- [Backspace on UTF-8 chars removes a single byte only](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/72)

Answer (score -1):

This is the expected behavior.

The `Backspace` key is not intended to delete but to backspace.

If you like to delete characters, use the `DEL` key.

Comment: Please stop posting answers that you know very well are misleading. On a PC, the key called Backspace is intended to delete the character to the left of the cursor, and the key called Delete is intended to delete the character to the right of the cursor. The key called Backspace is the tty erase key and the key called Delete has no tty equivalent.

Comment: Please stop answering when you are missing the needed skills. This is not a Microsoft group but a UNIX group and on UNIX, the default is that backspace does nothing special but DEL deletes to the left of the current position. There are some `applications` like bash that behave different but the OP wrote that he is running an own program and thus gets the default behavior. and BTW: Linux behaves the same if you have no access to UNIX.

Comment: The DEL key *is* BackSpace (if the stty erase character is set to DEL, which is usually the case). DEL ≠ Delete.

Comment: The default is DEL == delete and given that the OP seems to have problems, it is unlikely that he changed the setup from the default.